# Gas cost when calling Ethereum view functions on remote or local node

Tags: solidity, web3js, nodes

There are dozen of sources on the internet that state the `view` functions, which are called externally (i.e. from oustide of contract), that do not call other contracts' functions and do not change the state of the contract - consume no GAS. **As long as the call is done on a `local node`**.

I would like to hear some clarifications about what exactly considered to be a `local node` and what is a `remote node`. And how exactly does it work with `web3.js` library.

1. Is the node only considered `local` when is run on local machine resources? i.e. addressed by `web3.js` by the domain name `localhost`.
2. Is the node still considered `local`, if I host it on `Azure` services? i.e. it's my own `local` node, which is publicly available in order to use it in the front-end. I no longer use the "localhost" domain to access it. But I want to use it in order to avoid paying GAS for `view` functions.
3. If I use a remote node such as `infura` - then do `view` functions start costing GAS?
4. **(in in case answer to previous question is yes)** Is this possible to publish my own `local` node (essentially making it a remote node), so the client would still be able to call it and spend no-gas on `view` function?
5. In cases when functions (otherwise-free when called locally) start costing GAS - is the cost taken from the contract?
6. **In cases when functions (otherwise-free when called locally) start costing GAS - does the `call` become a `transaction` to cover the cost? (connected to previous question)**
7. Is it so that when `web3.js` is used on the `front-end` then node is always `remote`. And when `web3.js` is used on the `back-end`, then the node is always `local` (unless local is not available, of course)?
8. How do you use `web3.js` on the `front-end`, to allow users querying `non-state-changing` contract functions without a cost? I guess this is my main question which kind of summarizes why I have so much confusion about local/remote node. :)
9. (optional - dApp architecture advice). Could you tell if there is a flaw or a global misconception in my understanding?
   If we always use the `remote` nodes on the `front-end` then there is no "free" transactions/calls by definition. It looks like there should always be an interface on top of the backend that accepts the "calls" from the front-end, essentially making them GAS-free. So there are always 2 instances of `web3.js` running. 1st - is the one that client uses to create paid transactions, 2nd - is running on the backend to make GAS-free calls that do not change state. Unless it is possible to make front-end `web3.js` to tell the node to use local resources for free.

**Backstory:** I am working on my first contract and I am new in the world of `blockchain`. I want to expose my contract on the internet so the user would be able to "work" with it. I don't want the user (or the contract itself) to pay for the view (non-state-changing) functions. Sorry if some questions are stupid. I don't own a node or a website (yet) :)

Please do not mark the topic as duplicate unless all questions are answered in the linked topic. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to answer your points:

1. A local node is a full node that you're connecting directly. Or a light node that has access to a full node. Remote nodes would be other nodes from the network that you communicate updates through transactions.
2. Yes, it would still be a local node.
3. No, view functions with Infura don't cost gas. They do have a limit on how much gas a call can burn, but it's just to avoid DDoS attacks from people. The gas won't be used, just calculated to avoid stuff like infinite loops that could clog their system.
4. Nop, gas can never be taken from the contract, it doesn't matter what type of function you call. There is a thing called the "Ethereum Gas Station Network", that you can use to subsidise your user's fees if you need to, for example to improve onboarding and UX. https://www.opengsn.org/

I think the other points have been answered, but let me know if you want more clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Developer advocate from [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com) here. I can provide a little more context here.

A view function is a read contract call. It doesn't change the state so it can be called without gas. It is usually called by [eth_call](https://docs.chainstack.com/api/ethereum/eth_call) method. Below is a sample eth_call request object:

```
{"method":"eth_call","params":[{"from":null,"to":"0x514910771AF9Ca656af840dff83E8264EcF986CA","data":"0x70a08231000000000000000000000000271682deb8c4e0901d1a1550ad2e64d568e69909"}, "latest"],"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}
```

To answer your question:

1. "A local node" in this context is the opposite of "the whole blockchain network". It can be your own local node, Azure node, or a node hosted by any RPC provider. It only means there is no tx sent to the blockchain. The execution is limited to the node itself.
2. Yes.
3. No, the `view function` does not cost gas in any context.
4. It is not necessary.
5. No, calling a `view function` does not cost gas in any context.
6. Nah, in fact, you can "call" a non `view` function( `write` function) without sending the transaction. It will simulate the execution before sending it as a real tx.
7. Nope.
8. For `web3.js` you can use [methods.myMethod.call](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-call) to call a smart contract method.
9. For blockchain, Gas fees are only deducted from the account when the transactions are mined/validated in a block. For `web3.js`, in over simplified terms: `methods.myMethod.call` doesn't cost gas, `methods.myMethod.send` send a transaction and if it is finalised, it costs gas.

I have written a [blog about eth_call](https://chainstack.com/deep-dive-into-eth_call/), and I think it can help
you/others understand how blockchain works.

Hope it helps, happy coding.